# Dagger 2 Component class generated only on project rebuild/build

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am working on the implementation of dagger 2 in my Android project, everything seems fine with the graph, the only problem is the component class is not getting auto generated, I have to explicitly build the project and only then I can see the generated component class which I can use . My gradle dependencies as follows

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

Using Android Studio 3.0 
Also wanted to try android-apt but it is deprecated for the latest android studio

So I am missing something here or some basics?

Comment: I didn't even know you could auto-generate this. I thought you'd always have to clean and build. Are you absolutely sure this is possible without the use of plugins?

Comment: I am using dagger for the first time, so I assumed the class are generated automatically without the need to build the project and I was not able to use the apt plugin because it is not compatible with the new android studio..and its forcing me to use annotationProcessor instead..